# Applications of Gelfond's constant

Tags: transcendental-numbers

Gelfond's constant is the transcendental number $e^\pi$ which is approximately equal to:

$$
23.140692632...
$$

Are there any useful (real-world) applications of this constant besides its appearance in the Gelfond-Schneider Theorem? Is is "used" in some field of mathematics in a productive manner?

Comment: Nope, there is no use.

Comment: You can use it to calculate the [volume of the n-dimensional ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball).

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder: Not really. It is (somewhat trivially) the sum of the volumes of the $2n$-dimensional unit ball balls over all $n\ge 1$, but (a) that is not particularly useful for calculating any of the individual volumes, and (b) adding volumes of different dimensions is of questionable meaningfulness anyway.

Comment: (correction: you need the $(2\cdot 0)$-dimensional unit ball, whose $0$-volume is $1$, too, or you get $e^\pi-1$).

Comment: This value can lead $(-1)^i=0.0432139182・・・$.